# Can I have remote ssh terminal access in PhpStorm?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ide, phpstorm

I develop locally using PhpStorm, Git and VirtualBox on my local machine. I use Git to handle the process of moving work to staging or production environments. Currently I'm using [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) (an excellent free tabbed ssh client for windows) to have terminal access to do things on staging and production servers.  **PhpStorm has a local terminal built in, but how would I use it to have multiple ssh terminal access?** (This way I can have local, remote staging, and remote production terminal access all from within my IDE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out!

On a fresh copy, PhpStorm will have `Tools > Terminal` to bring up the local terminal. To have additional ssh terminal access, this is what I did...

1. Setup servers

```
1.1) File > Settings > (Type: "Deployment" into the search box)
1.2) Hit the + button and fill in the necessary fields into the connection tab.
1.3) Click on the "Mappings" tab and clear the field "Local path"
     since we will only be using the terminal.
1.4) Repeat Steps 1.2 and 1.3 for each server you want a terminal tab for.
1.5) Don't set any of these as default, so that you will be prompted to choose
     a server in Step #2 below...
```

[image]

2. Start a remote terminal tab (this will also open up local terminal)

```
2.1) Tools > Start SSH session (this option doesn't appear until Step #1 is   
     completed)
2.2) You will be prompted to select a server from Step #1.
     The terminal window appears and a new tab appears next to "local" in the
     terminal window.
```

[image]

EDIT: (Thanks to Dan Dascalescu) you may want to also ensure the `SSH Remote Run` plugin is enabled. It's enabled by default in PhpStorm 8 (not sure about earlier versions).

Comment: SFTP was the secret ingredient I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm has a plugin called ["SSH Remote Run"](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/running-ssh-terminal.html).

[image: Remote SSH]

See also the [built-in terminal](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools).

Comment: I'm looking for terminal access. A place where I can run server commands. I use Git for what I think you are describing?

Comment: The link to phpStorm's doc is confusing IMO. I had read the link before posting this question. You can see it's very different from what I had to discover in my answer. But let me give you a +1 for posting the link to the docs and also mentioning that the SSH Remote Run plugin must be selected (it is by default on my version, PhpStorm 8)